# AppBarLayout.onCreateDrawableState NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appbarlayout

We are encountering way too many of these crashes mostly on Samsung 6.0.1 devices. We even got the same device with the same os version and still can't reproduce it on our own. We are getting other inflate exceptions probably they are related.

Is there a workaround for this issue ?

support lib version - 24.2.1

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Exception android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:551)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:429)
com.myapp.profile.ProfileFragment.onCreateView (ProfileFragment.java:163)
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2080)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1108)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1290)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run (BackStackRecord.java:801)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction (FragmentManager.java:1638)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss (BackStackRecord.java:679)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate (FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1240)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1088)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure (ViewPager.java:1614)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild (CoordinatorLayout.java:700)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure (CoordinatorLayout.java:767)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1464)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:747)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:629)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.onMeasure (SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:804)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure (DrawerLayout.java:1085)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1464)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:747)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:629)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure (PhoneWindow.java:3143)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:2644)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:1599)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1891)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1487)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7450)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:920)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:695)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:631)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:906)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:657)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:776)
android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:966)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:843)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:855)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:855)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:527)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:429)
com.myapp.profile.ProfileFragment.onCreateView (ProfileFragment.java:163)
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2080)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1108)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1290)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run (BackStackRecord.java:801)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction (FragmentManager.java:1638)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss (BackStackRecord.java:679)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate (FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1240)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1088)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure (ViewPager.java:1614)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild (CoordinatorLayout.java:700)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure (CoordinatorLayout.java:767)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1464)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:747)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:629)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.onMeasure (SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:804)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure (DrawerLayout.java:1085)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1464)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:747)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:629)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure (PhoneWindow.java:3143)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:2644)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:1599)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:631)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:776)
android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:966)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:843)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:855)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:855)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:527)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:429)
com.myapp.profile.ProfileFragment.onCreateView (ProfileFragment.java:163)
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2080)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1108)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1290)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run (BackStackRecord.java:801)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction (FragmentManager.java:1638)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss (BackStackRecord.java:679)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate (FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1240)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1088)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure (ViewPager.java:1614)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild (CoordinatorLayout.java:700)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure (CoordinatorLayout.java:767)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1464)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:747)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:629)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.onMeasure (SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:804)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure (DrawerLayout.java:1085)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1464)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:747)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:629)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure (PhoneWindow.java:3143)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:2644)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.onCreateDrawableState (AppBarLayout.java:494)
android.view.View.getDrawableState (View.java:18365)
android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable (View.java:18614)
android.view.View.setBackground (View.java:18551)
android.view.View.<init> (View.java:4621)
android.view.ViewGroup.<init> (ViewGroup.java:589)
android.widget.LinearLayout.<init> (LinearLayout.java:202)
android.widget.LinearLayout.<init> (LinearLayout.java:198)
android.widget.LinearLayout.<init> (LinearLayout.java:194)
android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.<init> (AppBarLayout.java:151)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:631)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:776)
android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:966)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:843)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:855)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:855)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:527)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:429)
com.myapp.profile.ProfileFragment.onCreateView (ProfileFragment.java:163)
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2080)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1108)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1290)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run (BackStackRecord.java:801)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction (FragmentManager.java:1638)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss (BackStackRecord.java:679)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate (FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1240)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1088)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure (ViewPager.java:1614)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild (CoordinatorLayout.java:700)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure (CoordinatorLayout.java:767)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1464)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:747)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:629)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.onMeasure (SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:804)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure (DrawerLayout.java:1085)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6328)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:20166)
```

Comment: Samsung should only sell vacuum cleaners. Never mind this. Are you setting some drawable to the appbar layout? Maybe statelistdrawable for the elevation? It's really messed up situation because the array of ints is primitive yet it throws like it is not initialized. This could be thrown due to permission if the app is moved to sd storage and drawable is read as normal file.

Comment: The same happened to me, but library 25.3.1

Comment: @mstrengis just to let you know: Android team fixed this issue and bugfix will be released soon - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37139450

Comment: @Javier Have you soluted it? I'm using 25.3.1 too.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when AppBarLayout tries to initialise its scrollbar - it's quite possible that your Activity style has default scrollbar style set up and AppBarLayout inherits it.

The simplest solution is to make sure AppBarLayout doesn't use scrollbar ever and just to do as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <!--YOUR LAYOUT-->

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I'm pretty sure I didn't see proper bug report for this issue in Android project, so I guess it's the time for me to report one.

**EDIT**

I've created example app to reproduce this issue - you can find it right [here](https://github.com/skrzyneckik/Android-Issues-Regression). When you launch app `issue-254934` on device with API22 - both AppBarLayout configurations work and for API23 and above one of them causes exactly the same exception as you've reported right here.

**EDIT**

[Issue-254923](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37139450) had been fixed and bugfix will be released in a future release

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you provide steps on how to reproduce that crash? We can't reproduce that crash by our selves

Comment: @mstrengis just to let you know, I've added example project to my answer